# Divert SMS programmatically in android

Tags: android, sms

I am sending text message through my app. Can we divert SMS to another number in android programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand the question correctly.

You want to forward received SMS to another number?
If thats the case use a broadcastreceiver to listen for the intent android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED.

Read the sms and send it to the other number

Answer (score 0):

If your app is the one sending the text message, you certainly have control over which number to send it to.

The question is rather vague but you can easily set a number for your debug build to default to instead of using the number provided.